# outcome from fair and non-fair dice, dice are chosen from other dice part1

Tags: probability, dice

> There're 3 dice, two are fair, one is not, it has an occurrences of $5$ instead of $4$.  That is the non-fair dice is ${1,2,3,5,5,6}.$
>   We choose one dice from the three randomly, and throw it twice. What is the probability that two rolls will show $5$.

If the dice is fair then the probability that $5$ is rolled twice in a throw is $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}$, if the dice is not fair then the probability is $\frac{2}{6} \times \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{9}$.

How do I take into account that a dice can be chosen from three?

Comment: What do you mean "if the dice is fair the probability is $\frac 16 \times \frac 16$"?

Comment: added the explanation in the question

Comment: Oh, are you saying the unfair die has faces $\{1,2,3,4,5,5\}$ or something like that?

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to say this

Comment: Assuming that I am interpreting your unfair die correctly, then use the law of total probability:  the answer is $\frac 16 \times \frac 16 \times P(fair) +\frac 26\times \frac 26 \times P(unfair)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split this up into two cases:

Case 1: Fair die

- The probability of getting a fair die is $\frac 2 3$
- The probability of two fives with a fair die is, as you found, $\frac 1 {36}$

Case 1: Non-fair die

- The probability of getting a fair die is $\frac 1 3$
- The probability of two fives with a fair die is, as you found, $\frac 1 {9}$

Then, multiply the probabilities within each case and add the results:
$$\frac 2 3\cdot\frac 1 {36}+\frac 1 3\cdot\frac 1 9=\frac 1 {18}$$

Splitting events up into exhaustive cases and multiplying within the cases/adding between the cases is called [the Law of Total Probability](http://www.probabilityformula.org/total-probability.html).

Comment: thanks! by that logic if there was a throw when the second roll came out to be $5$. the probability that the first roll was $4$ is $\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3}\times 0$ ?

Comment: @Yos Unfortunately, this is a bit more complicated problem where you need to combine Bayes' Rule with Law of Total Probability, so $\frac 2 3\times \frac 1 6+\frac 1 3\times 0$ is not correct. Please ask this problem in a separate question.

Comment: posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070920/outcome-from-fair-and-non-fair-dice-dice-are-chosen-from-other-dice-part2

Answer (score 0):

The probability to get a fair die is $\frac{2}{3}$ and the chance to get the unfair die is $\frac{1}{3}$. Combining this with your results yields
$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{9} = \frac{1}{18}$$
as probability of throwing two fives.