# outcome from fair and non-fair dice, dice are chosen from other dice part2

Tags: probability, dice

> There're 3 dice, two are fair, one is not. The non-fair dice has an occurrence of $5$ instead of $4$. That is the non-fair dice is $\{1,2,3,5,5,6\}.$
>   We choose one dice from the three randomly, and throw it twice. Suppose the second roll in a throw returned $5$. What is the probability that the first roll returned $4$?

In the related question I posted earlier ([outcome from fair and non-fair dice, dice are chosen from other dice part1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070862/outcome-from-fair-and-non-fair-dice-dice-are-chosen-from-other-dice-part1)) it was suggested that the solution will require using Bayes Rule. This is my version: $B$ - the second roll returns $5$. $A$ - the first roll returns $4$. According to Bayes rule: $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3} \times 0}{\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{2}{6}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your method is that you did not calculate $P(A \cap B)$ correctly. $P(A \cap B)$ is the probability that the first roll is $4$ and the second roll is $5$, but you just found the probability that the first roll is $4$. Let's break this up into two cases:

Case 1: Fair die

- The probability of getting a fair die is $\frac 2 3$
- The probability of rolling $4$ on first roll is $\frac 1 6$
- The probability of rolling $5$ on second roll is $\frac 1 6$

Case 1: Non-Fair die

- The probability of getting a fair die is $\frac 1 3$
- The probability of rolling $4$ on first roll is $0$
- The probability of rolling $5$ on second roll is $\frac 2 6$

Now, by the Law of Total Probability, multiply within the cases and add between the cases to get:
$$P(A \cap B)=\frac 2 3\cdot \frac 1 6\cdot \frac 1 6+\frac 1 3\cdot 0\cdot\frac 2 6=\frac 1 {54}$$
By Bayes' Rule, we get:
$$P(A | B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac 1 {54}}{\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{2}{6}}=\frac 1 {12}$$

Comment: what bothers me is that $B$ in the denominator is not the same $B$ as in the nominator.

Comment: @Yos I am not sure as to what you mean. The $B$ in the numerator and denominator both mean "rolling $5$ on second roll." I have edited my answer above to make this more clear.

Comment: the problem is don't see how the nominator is developed with events notation. According to what rule $P(A \cap B)$ becomes the sum of products and thus I don't see the part of the nominator that should be identical to the $P(B)$ in the denominator.

Comment: Intuitively the solution makes sense but I need to prove this with events first.

Comment: Let's say $C=\text{fair die}$ and $C^\text{c}=\text{non fair die}$. Then, I calculated $P(A \cap B)$ as $P(C)P((A \cap B) | C)+P(C^\text{c})P((A \cap B) | C^\text{c})$ using Law of Total Probability. Now, given the type of die, $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other since the first roll does not affect the second roll, so I split it up into the following using the Law of Multiplication: $$P(A \cap B)=P(C)P(A | C)P(B | C)+P(C^\text{c})P(A | C^\text{c})P(B | C^\text{c})$$ This is similar to the formula you used to compute $P(B)$: $$P(B)=P(C)P(B | C)+P(C^\text{c})P(B | C^\text{c})$$

Comment: Thanks! I posted another question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072348/outcome-from-fair-and-non-fair-dice-dice-are-chosen-from-other-dice-part3#2072445) from the series and 2 unequal answers were given. I'd appreciate if you could help decide which one is correct.